# What exactly is the type of beer I made?

Tags: beer-styles

I'm a newbie just 3 weeks into brewing my first beer. Homebrewing is not very common where I live so I had to made do with what was available. I started with malt extract OG 1.075, yeast Safale Ale S-04 Whitbread Strain and Cooper's Ale. Hops: Cascade. FG is 1.01

What exactly should I call what I have brewed.

Thanks a million.

Comment: Unless it's a competition, call it whatever you want ;) Evil Zymurgist is right  that "American Ale" seems most appropriate, but if it's only for you and your friends, only thing that matters is: what name would you see fit?

Comment: Yes Molot, you're right. I was just wondering what type so that if the time ever came, I could say I made an IPA or I made XYZ lager, etc.

Comment: It might be American IPA, in a way... depends how hoppy and bitter it is.

Comment: Maybe call it "beer"?

Comment: @MikePainter well it's definatly an Ale, not a Lager. Lager Yeast and cold fermentation make lagers. Your hops are american, if the IBU is above 60 it could be styled as a Double IPA, or above 50 as an American Strong Ale.

Answer (score 5):

**Congratulations on your first brew!**

I would suggest putting the ingedient details into some brew software many are free in the form of phone apps or web based. Give it a Google.

The limited information you have given isn't enough to go on. We need malt type and amount, batch volume, hop weight, age and boil duration of hops to even guess a style based on vitals.

[bjcp.org has the 2015 style guidlines](http://www.bjcp.org/docs/2015_Guidelines_Beer.pdf) where you can compare your vitals, ingredients and fermentation type to established styles.

But ulitmatly, it will come down to how it tastes, smells and appears once it's done .

With the limited details it leans to a strong American ale 8.5% ABV while not a style in itself it's a start. 22A is Double IPA with IBU 60-120, 22B is American Strong Ale IBU 50-100. There's a lot of differences between the two, though the IBUs overlap.